# Dart mqtt_client The broker is not responding to the connection request message correctly The return code is MqttConnectReturnCode.identifierRejected

Tags: flutter, dart, mqtt

I always return identifierRejected when I use mqtt_client library to connect with mqtts
The parameters are confirmed to be correct, I am connected to the mqttx client normally

code sample

```dart
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_server_client.dart';

void mqttInit(String server, String username, String password) async {
  // Append a timestamp to the ClientID to prevent duplicate connections
  String clientId = 'pigpad_';
  clientId += DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

  print('server: $server');
  print('username: $username');
  print('password: $password');
  print('clientId: $clientId');
  print('**************************');

  final client = MqttServerClient(server, clientId);

  client.logging(on: true);
  client.setProtocolV311();
  client.secure = true;
  client.port = 8883;

  client.keepAlivePeriod = 20;
  client.onDisconnected = () {
    print('Disconnected');
  };

  client.onConnected = () {
    print('Connected');
  };

  client.onSubscribed = (String topic) {
    print('Subscribed: $topic');
  };

  client.pongCallback = () {
    print('pong');
  };

  client.onBadCertificate = (dynamic a) => true;

  final connMess = MqttConnectMessage()
      .withClientIdentifier(clientId)
      .withWillTopic('willtopic')
      .withWillMessage('My Will message')
      .startClean()
      .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
  client.connectionMessage = connMess;

  try {
    await client.connect(username, password);
    print('Connection successful');
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    print('Connection failed - $e');
    client.disconnect();
  }
}
```

output

```sh
flutter: server: iot-device.wens.com.cn
flutter: username: 61c039b231b95a797fc5eb1d_62231e5eaf26d3b9f3491219
flutter: password: 08915b24f1b28bc915ec7d6e9531e8e0
flutter: clientId: pigpad_1646475545342
flutter: **************************
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.343679 -- Authenticating with username '{61c039b231b95a797fc5eb1d_62231e5eaf26d3b9f3491219}' and password '{08915b24f1b28bc915ec7d6e9531e8e0}'
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.343679 -- MqttClient::checkCredentials - Username length (49) exceeds the max recommended in the MQTT spec.
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.343679 -- MqttClient::checkCredentials - Password length (32) exceeds the max recommended in the MQTT spec.
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.344679 -- MqttClient::connect - keep alive is enabled with a value of 20 seconds
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.344679 -- MqttConnectionKeepAlive:: Initialised with a keep alive value of 20 seconds
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.344679 -- MqttConnectionKeepAlive:: Disconnect on no ping response is disabled
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.344679 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::connect - server iot-device.wens.com.cn, port 8883
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.344679 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect entered
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.344679 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - initiating connection try 0, auto reconnect in progress false
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.344679 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - secure selected
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.344679 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - calling connect
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.345677 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - entered
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.390766 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - securing socket
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.390766 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - start listening
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.390766 -- MqttServerConnection::_startListening
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.391767 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - connection complete
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.391767 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect sending connect message
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.391767 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::sendMessage - MQTTMessage of type MqttMessageType.connect
Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connect, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 0
Connect Variable Header: ProtocolName=MQTT, ProtocolVersion=4, ConnectFlags=Connect Flags: Reserved1=false, CleanStart=true, WillFlag=true, WillQos=MqttQos.atLeastOnce, WillRetain=false, PasswordFlag=true, UserNameFlag=true, KeepAlive=20
MqttConnectPayload - client identifier is : pigpad_1646475545342
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.394766 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - pre sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.467510 -- MqttConnection::_onData
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.467510 -- MqttServerConnection::_onData - message received MQTTMessage of type MqttMessageType.connectAck
Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connectAck, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 2
Connect Variable Header: TopicNameCompressionResponse={0}, ReturnCode={MqttConnectReturnCode.identifierRejected}
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.468511 -- MqttServerConnection::_onData - message available event fired
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.469512 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_connectAckProcessor
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.469512 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_connectAckProcessor connection rejected
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.469512 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_performConnectionDisconnect entered
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.470507 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase:: cancelling connect timer
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.470507 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - post sleep, state = Connection status is disconnected with return code of identifierRejected and a disconnection origin of none
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.470507 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - initiating connection try 1, auto reconnect in progress false
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.470507 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - secure selected
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.470507 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - calling connect
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.470507 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - entered
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.473522 -- MqttConnectionBase::_onDone - calling disconnected callback
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.518434 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - securing socket
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.518434 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - start listening
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.519434 -- MqttServerConnection::_startListening
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.519434 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - connection complete
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.519434 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect sending connect message
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.519434 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::sendMessage - MQTTMessage of type MqttMessageType.connect
Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connect, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 145
Connect Variable Header: ProtocolName=MQTT, ProtocolVersion=4, ConnectFlags=Connect Flags: Reserved1=false, CleanStart=true, WillFlag=true, WillQos=MqttQos.atLeastOnce, WillRetain=false, PasswordFlag=true, UserNameFlag=true, KeepAlive=20
MqttConnectPayload - client identifier is : pigpad_1646475545342
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.522435 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - pre sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.583432 -- MqttConnection::_onData
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.583432 -- MqttServerConnection::_onData - message received MQTTMessage of type MqttMessageType.connectAck
Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connectAck, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 2
Connect Variable Header: TopicNameCompressionResponse={0}, ReturnCode={MqttConnectReturnCode.identifierRejected}
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.585438 -- MqttServerConnection::_onData - message available event fired
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.586433 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_connectAckProcessor
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.586433 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_connectAckProcessor connection rejected
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.586433 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_performConnectionDisconnect entered
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.586433 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase:: cancelling connect timer
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.586433 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - post sleep, state = Connection status is disconnected with return code of identifierRejected and a disconnection origin of none
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.586433 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - initiating connection try 2, auto reconnect in progress false
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.586433 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - secure selected
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.586433 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - calling connect
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.586433 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - entered
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.592434 -- MqttConnectionBase::_onDone - calling disconnected callback
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.634444 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - securing socket
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.634444 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - start listening
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.634444 -- MqttServerConnection::_startListening
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.634444 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - connection complete
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.634444 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect sending connect message
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.634444 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::sendMessage - MQTTMessage of type MqttMessageType.connect
Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connect, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 145
Connect Variable Header: ProtocolName=MQTT, ProtocolVersion=4, ConnectFlags=Connect Flags: Reserved1=false, CleanStart=true, WillFlag=true, WillQos=MqttQos.atLeastOnce, WillRetain=false, PasswordFlag=true, UserNameFlag=true, KeepAlive=20
MqttConnectPayload - client identifier is : pigpad_1646475545342
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.635449 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - pre sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.701446 -- MqttConnection::_onData
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.701446 -- MqttServerConnection::_onData - message received MQTTMessage of type MqttMessageType.connectAck
Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connectAck, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 2
Connect Variable Header: TopicNameCompressionResponse={0}, ReturnCode={MqttConnectReturnCode.identifierRejected}
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.701446 -- MqttServerConnection::_onData - message available event fired
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.701446 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_connectAckProcessor
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.701446 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_connectAckProcessor connection rejected
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.701446 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_performConnectionDisconnect entered
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.701446 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase:: cancelling connect timer
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.702448 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - post sleep, state = Connection status is disconnected with return code of identifierRejected and a disconnection origin of none
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.702448 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect failed
flutter: Connection failed - mqtt-client::NoConnectionException: The maximum allowed connection attempts ({3}) were exceeded. The broker is not responding to the connection request message correctly The return code is MqttConnectReturnCode.identifierRejected
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.703450 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::disconnect - entered
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.703450 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_performConnectionDisconnect entered
flutter: 4-2022-03-05 18:19:05.703450 -- MqttConnectionKeepAlive::stop - stopping keep alive
flutter: Disconnected
```

flutter doctor -v

```sh
PS D:\Project> flutter doctor -v
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1415], locale zh-CN)
    • Flutter version 2.10.1 at D:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision db747aa133 (3 weeks ago), 2022-02-09 13:57:35 -0600
    • Engine revision ab46186b24
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\13710\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)       
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio 生成工具 2019 16.11.9)        
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
    • Visual Studio 生成工具 2019 version 16.11.32106.194
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] VS Code (version 1.65.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\13710\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.36.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1415]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.102
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 98.0.1108.50
    ! Device ac107f92 is not authorized.
      You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.

[!] HTTP Host Availability
    X HTTP host https://maven.google.com/ is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host:

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I use MQTTX client to connect server successfully

- https://s2.loli.net/2022/03/05/KOjJcLHF3AQ4g8p.jpg
- https://s2.loli.net/2022/03/05/zDLWJX5QlwSspHm.jpg

Comment: The first 3 lines after the line of stars in the log look pretty clear to me....

Comment: Your screenshots show a connection using a different client id. Given that the error is "identifierRejected" (which [the spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html) says means "The Client identifier is correct UTF-8 but not allowed by the Server") it seems likely that is relevant (we cannot know without access to the broker because that is what is returning the error). Note: I hope that's not a valid username/password in your logs :-).

Answer (score 0):

Try using .authenticateAs('username', 'password') on the connMess and replace username and password with the actual values.